# How do I compare the Time.Elapsed against a condition?

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I have created a simple console application where the User must complete a certain task and the time take to do this is measured. To measure the time take I am using the **Stopwatch** class and have created a **stopwatch** variable that stopped after the User completed the task

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

I then store the time taken in a variable called **timeTaken**

```
TimeSpan timeTaken = watch.Elapsed;
```

My question is, is there a way to compare the value of this variable to another preset time? **For example Is timeTaken < 5 seconds**. I have created a basic if statement to demonstrate what I need.

```
string elapsedTime = String.Format("\n{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",timeTaken.Minutes, timeTaken.Seconds, timeTaken.Milliseconds);

if (elapsedTime == "00:03:00")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Really Fast");
}
else if (elapsedTime == "00:05:00")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fast");
}
```

Not sure if this comparison is possible I have looked around but couldn't find anything, thanks in advance.

Comment: Compare TimeSpans, not strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The structure contains properties that return the total number of milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours or days, so just use the appropriate property. For example:

```
if (timeTaken.TotalSeconds <= 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Really Fast");
}
else if (timeTaken.TotalSeconds <= 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fast");
}
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly, ill mark it as the answer when I can. Thank you for your help Sean.

Comment: Also note that you can compare TimeSpans directly to each other, so for example you could put `if (timeTaken <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)` or (if you want to be fancy) `var threeSecs = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3); ... if (timeTaken <= threeSecs)`

Comment: Thank you Matthew, ill give that  try to.